# Is a chemical gradient part of the grand potential energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, potential, entropy, potential-energy

Recently I was trying to write an intuitive explanation of entropy, and wanted to check my understanding of a simple system is accurate.  Here we have a box with two sides:

[image: box with a particle and a dotted line in the middle]

Starting off, there is a particle of an ideal gas on one side.  We remove a barrier at the middle, or perhaps there is no barrier and we simply *forget* which side it is on.  Either way, the particle now ranges over twice the volume and its entropy changes by +k<sub>B</sub> ln 2 and its associated thermal energy changes by +k<sub>B</sub>T ln 2.

Then I was thinking, where does that energy come from?  I've summarized what I hope is valid information about the different kinds of energy present below.  I know the energy has to be conserved in any closed system.  The energy expended is also clearly a sort of *free* energy, because we could put in a tiny piston at the dotted line and do a reversible process extracting work in which the entropy does not increase, which would mean the temperature of the particle would have to be reduced by half to keep S x T constant.

[image: table of enthalpy, SxT, PxV, Heimholtz free energy]

Somewhat to my surprise, the energy apparently does not come from PV.  The pressure of the particle is now half as much because the volume is twice as much.

So far as I know, the only place left is the Heimholtz free energy.  This can be subdivided into chemical potential and grand potential; at least according to Wikipedia, ${\displaystyle \Phi _{\rm {G}}\ {\stackrel {\mathrm {def} }{=}}\ U-TS-\mu N}$, where F = U-TS is the Heimholtz energy.  The $\mu N$ bit is a chemical energy *per particle*, and we've done nothing to change the number or type of particles.

The reason why I'm asking the question is that the things I found to read about grand potential seem very esoteric, referring to Boltzmann distributions and such, whereas saying it includes the energy of a chemical concentration gradient seems very simple.  ([This exception](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.1014) seems helpful and interesting, but doesn't speak very directly) I suspect grand potential must contain other 'basic stuff' like the height of a weight inside a grandfather clock, if we define the volume inside the clock as our 'system'.  *Is my reasoning here correct, and if so is there an approachable and freely accessible source I could use to further explains grand potential in such basic terms?*

Comment: If we disregard QM effects, this is a simple mechanical system. Statistical mechanics or thermodynamics doesn't apply. If we assume elastic collisions with the walls, the energy of the particle is simply $E_k = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$, with or without the central wall.

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski I agree with that; it's a closed system neither gaining or losing mass-energy.  The issue is only to be clear about how the energy is subcategorized as the entropy changes.

Answer (score 1):

When you remove the barrier the entropy changes by $\Delta S = k T \ln 2$. The energy of the system does *not* change. Still, $T S$ represents energy -- but of what kind? In this case it is the energy that *we* must spend to compress the system back to half its expanded size while keeping temperature at $T$. To do this we push the right wall against the bouncing particle.

The thermodynamic function that embodies this work, as you correctly say, is free energy. The Helmholtz energy is $A = U-TS$ and since $U$ has not changed, we have $$\Delta A = T \Delta S$$
We interpret $A$ as the work associated with the partitioning of closed system (the big box) at constant $T$.

**An Information Theoretical twist**

If we had access to Maxwell's demon we would just put back the partition as a soon as the particle passes to the left half. No work needed in this case. We may view the lost work as work that arises from our ignorance ("lost knowledge", if we ever possessed it) as to where the particle is.

Comment: This is reasssuring to hear, but I was really looking to see confirmation that the energy of a concentration gradient is part of the *grand potential*.  For some reason I haven't seen the sources saying this specific thing outright, so I still worry I might be misunderstanding the term.

Comment: @ Mike Serfas In thermodynamics the proper gradient for molecular transport is not concentration but chemical potential. This is the term $\mu N$. If we write the first law in the form $dU = T dS - P dV + \mu dN$, all the terms on the RHS represents energy: thermal, $PV$ and chemical.

Comment: *that* explains it - I was confused about the meaning of the chemical potential.  I'm not sure if that's because "internal" was left out of the phrase or some other reason...